# passing contents from multiple lists generated in different functions to a file

Tags: python

I have 3 functions which generate three different lists. I am trying to generate a mel script which is a text file which will write the values taken from these three lists. All three lists have same number of values. All the values in these lists are animation data and therefore they have to be passed in a mel script to drive an animation in Maya. All these lists values are floating point numbers.

```
func1() :
    generates tlist

func2() :
    generates list1

func3() :
    generates list2  

def mel_script() :
  """ Generating the mel script with the animation information """
  with open("mel.txt", "w") as melFile :
      melFile.write(setKeyframe "blend_shape.lip_round";
                    setKeyframe "blend_shape.jaw_open";

                    currentTime 0 ;
                    setAttr "blend_shape.lip_round" 0;
                    setAttr "blend_shape.jaw_open" 0;
                    setKeyframe -breakdown 0 -hierarchy none -controlPoints 0 -shape 0 {"blend_shape"}; 

                    currentTime (first value of tlist) ;
                    setAttr "blend_shape.lip_round" (first value of list1);
                    setAttr "blend_shape.jaw_open" (first value of list2);
                    setKeyframe -breakdown 0 -hierarchy none -controlPoints 0 -shape 0 {"blend_shape"};

                    currentTime (second value of tlist) ;
                    setAttr "blend_shape.lip_round" (second value of list1);
                    setAttr "blend_shape.jaw_open" (second value of list2);
                    setKeyframe -breakdown 0 -hierarchy none -controlPoints 0 -shape 0 {"blend_shape"};                       
                   ........
                   ........
```

The first 6 lines in the file are default. The text in the mel script should continue up until the last values from each list. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip`.

```
for x, y, z in zip(func1(), func2(), func3()):
    melFile.write("currentTime %f" % x)
    melFile.write('setAttr "blend_shape.lip_round" %f' % y)
    melFile.write('setAttr "blend_shape.jaw_open" %f' % z)
```

Add in all of the other boilerplate you want to generate, and try to think of better variable names than `x`, `y`, `z`.

Comment: I have to pass the all the lists as arguments in mel_script() function? But where do I call this function?

Comment: @zingy: who's talking about passing arguments? There's no function definition in the snippet I posted.

Comment: Sorry I haven't understood yet. But where do I place this code? Is it inside mel_script() function?

Comment: @zingy: yes, inside `mel_script`.

Comment: Can the values of the lists generated inside the functions be passed like that? I mean by just referring to the functions?

Comment: @zingy: if a function returns a list, you can just handle it as a single object, no matter how large it is. That's the power of modern programming languages :)

Comment: Cheers..would try it and get back.

Comment: I tried the above solution and it was working fine yesterday on a test code. Then I added it to my code and it didn't show any errors but when I run it today it gives and error on the 'for loop' as "for p in lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_bezier : TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable"