# generating a mel script

Tags: python

Following the question I had asked yesterday which is here [passing contents from multiple lists generated in different functions to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205400/passing-contents-from-multiple-lists-generated-in-different-functions-to-a-file/8205453#8205453) I have written the code. Part of the code is below,

```
def lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_bezier(x_n, p0, p3) :
    """ Calculating sampling points using rational bezier curve equation"""
    lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_p_u_list = []
    u = x_n
    p1 = p0
    p2 = p3

    lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_p_u = math.pow(1 - u, 3) * p0 + 3 * u * math.pow(1 - u, 2) * p1 \
                                 + 3 * (1 - u) * math.pow(u, 2) * p2 + math.pow(u, 3) * p3
    lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_p_u = lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_p_u * w
    d = math.pow(1 - u, 3) * w + 3 * u * w * math.pow(1 - u, 2) + 3 * (1 - u) * w * math.pow(u, 2) + math.pow(u, 3) * w
    lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_p_u = lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_p_u / d

    print "p(u): ", lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_p_u
    lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_p_u_list.append(lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_p_u)

    return lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_p_u_list

def mel_script() :
  """ Generating the mel script with the animation information """
    print "\n The mel script generated for the input speech with the chosen energy level" 
    with open("mel.txt", "w") as melFile :
        melFile.write('setKeyframe "BS_stickyLips_SL_recept.head_geo_stickyLips_wire";'
                      'setKeyframe "BS_stickyLips_baseSL_recept.head_geo";'
                      'setKeyframe "BS_stickyLips_wireSL_recept.head_geo";'
                      'setKeyframe "blend_shape.lip_round";'
                      'setKeyframe "blend_shape.jaw_open";'
                      'setKeyframe "blend_shape.lips_spread";'
                      'setKeyframe "blend_shape.lips_part";'
                      'setKeyframe "blend_shape.lower_lip_under_upper_teeth";')

    for p in lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_bezier :
        melFile.write('setAttr "blend_shape.jaw_open" %f ;' % p )
        melFile.write('setKeyframe -breakdown 0 -hierarchy none -controlPoints 0 -shape 0 {"blend_shape"};')
```

But I am getting an error which is,

```
    for p in lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_bezier :
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_bezier` is a **function**. The error message clearly tells it, there is no way around it.

You might *believe* that `lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_bezier` is an iterable, but it is not.

Now, mine is just a guess, but I believe what you want to do is something like:

```
def mel_script(lip_var):
    '''The mel script generated for the input speech with the chosen energy level'''
    with open("mel.txt", "w") as melFile :
        melFile.write('setKeyframe "BS_stickyLips_SL_recept.head_geo_stickyLips_wire";'
                      'setKeyframe "BS_stickyLips_baseSL_recept.head_geo";'
                      'setKeyframe "BS_stickyLips_wireSL_recept.head_geo";'
                      'setKeyframe "blend_shape.lip_round";'
                      'setKeyframe "blend_shape.jaw_open";'
                      'setKeyframe "blend_shape.lips_spread";'
                      'setKeyframe "blend_shape.lips_part";'
                      'setKeyframe "blend_shape.lower_lip_under_upper_teeth";')
    for p in lip_var:    # Check this out!!!
        melFile.write('setAttr "blend_shape.jaw_open" %f ;' % p )
```

---

**EDIT (see comments)**: I think there is some basic misunderstanding on how python works going on here... In python (as in most programming languages!) when you declare a function, you declare its name and *what arguments it expects*.

If you are trying to pass 5 lists to `mel_script`, when you declare `mel_script` you should say so:

```
def mel_script(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5):
    # Your code here should work with list1, list2, etc...
```

Then, when calling `mel_script`, you need to pass these lists to it. If such lists are generated by functions (say `f1`, `f2`, `f3`...). You could do it all in one line with:

```
mel_script(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), f5())
```

otherwise you have to store the lists in temporary variables and pass those to `mel_scirpt`:

```
tmp1 = f1()
tmp2 = f2()
tmp3 = f3()
tmp4 = f4()
tmp5 = f5()
mel_script(tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, tmp4, tmp5)
```

In the above examples note that `f1()` has round parenthesis denoting the fact you are **calling** the function named `f1`. If you would omit those, then you would be passing the *function itself, not its result*.

In reality there are cleverer ways to achieve this (like passing a variable number of arguments, or using closures, but from your question I understand that you are not (yet!) proficient with python, so it would be better to stick with this method for now! :)

HTH!

Comment: is lip_var in your code the function which generates the list?

Comment: @zingy - nope, is the iterable (variable) where the `lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_p_u_list` list returned by `lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_bezier` function was stored.

Comment: @zingy - are you trying to pass a function [f1] as an argument to another function [f2]? If yes, should the arguments to be fed to `f1` be given in `f2`, or prior to sending `f1` to `f2`?

Comment: Where do I include the two lines with 'tmp' ? Its just not 1 function I am working with. There are 5 functions generating 5 lists and I have to pass the values from those 5 lists to each line of the mel script. I am so ignorant that I cannot understand the connection.

Comment: Please if you have a look at the previous post then you might understand. In the previous post I just wrote func1() as an example but I actually have arguments with the functions.

Comment: Cheers. I was making a mistake in the first place by creating too many functions. I would sort the code first then I guess this will resolve.

Answer (score 3):

You are not calling the function.  To call it, use

```
lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_bezier(x_n, p0, p3)
```

and substitute appropriate values for the parameters.

Comment: This function is called somewhere else in the code. I am trying to use the contents of the list generated in this function to use in the mel_script() function.

Comment: I got what you mean. But the arguments passed in this function are generated in other functions so they won't be recognized here if I pass them.

Comment: @zingy: So how would you expect to be able to run the code of the function `lower_lip_under_upper_teeth_bezier()` if you don't know what values the parameters are supposed to have?  What should the function do without knowing its parameters?  You seem to have some serious misconceptions here, and I'm not sure if we can resolve them by answering a few SO questions.  Probably you'll have to put some effort in [learning the basics](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/) first.

Comment: @ Sven Marnach I know from where the arguments are passing and the values are going from other functions as this function is called in another function where the arguments are generated. Its a long code so I didn't post it.

Comment: @zingy: But then, how do you think then function `mel_script()` knows what other function call somewhere else you might be referring to?  I understood your previous comment, and I appreciate you didn't post the whole code.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I think I just got the solution. Because there are too many functions so it was getting complicated. But all these functions are doing the same thing I just have to pass different values each time. so instead of generating so many functions I just call the function as many times as needed with different values. So silly of me. Now that this will reduce to just one function it will work. Cheers

Comment: @zingy: Glad you found the problem.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Or maybe I'm just being overconfident. I still have to sort it out. I 'm sure the problem will get a lot simpler but I would still have some queries then perhaps I would bother you again.. lol..